# How to update ImageMagick (imagick) for PHP

Tags: 12.04, php

I've installed ImageMagick for PHP using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

But the version installed (namely ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2012-08-17 Q16) is not the latest version (currently 6.8.6) and it has some bugs with prevent a PHP script to run.

So... how to upgrade to the latest version?

Idiot-proof step by step instructions would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that version 6.6.9.7 is the latest for Ubuntu 12.04.  Now there is a debate that the newer version may or may not work.  If you would like to update, you may want to try downloading the [latest version](ftp://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/ImageMagick/), and installing it.

If using it is important, maybe you can consider upgrading Ubuntu to 13.04

Take a look at [Ubuntu Updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/imagemagick), and click on the link under Links.